# Need help figuring out short regex - how to match 1 a char, then either of a set including the char, then another char

Tags: regex

My regex does not match phrases as intended, and I don't know if it's possible or not to do what I'm trying to.

Intended match (as string progresses)

- phrase starts with *t*
- FIRST character after beginning *t* must not be *t*
- has any number of *t* or *y* characters (can be 0)
- must end with *y*

Should match:

- *ty*
- *tytyyy*

Should not match:

- *tty*
- *tyt*

Regex

```
/t[ty]*y/
```

this will match *ty*
but it will also match *tty*

Other Regex

```
t(?!t)[ty]*y
```

this matches *tty* for some reason, even though I clearly specify there cannot be a *t* after the initial *t*, after which there can be any number of *t* and *y*, and it should end with *y*?

I am trying to find a middle-ground but no matter how I change my regex, it ends up failing at least 1 other check I mentioned in the list above.

Comment: You could use `^t(?!t).*y$`, `(?!t)` being a *negative lookahead*. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SWwCOe/1)

Comment: You are missing boundaries, so in this case you get partial matches. It also depends on what you want to match in which context. You specify "phrase starts with t" but is that at the start of the string, and do you want to match the whole string? Or do you only want to match a word that consists of only word characters? You could also use word boundaries `\bt(?!t)[ty]*y\b` but that would also have a partial match in `#ty#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^t([^t][ty]*)?y$` - [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/5CWWDE/2)

- ^ - start of word
- t - begins with t
- (

  - [^t] - a non-t character
  - .* - any following characters
- )? - above are optional (they are within the group)
- y - ends in y
- $ - end of word

---

Matches:

- ty
- tytyyy

Does not match:

- tty
- tyt

---

Answer to comment:
`t(?!t)[ty]*y`

- The reason the above doesn't work is because you do not specify a beginning/end using ^ and $
- t - at the start is okay
- (?!t) - is a negative lookahead, instead of this to exclude a letter t after the beginning letter t you can use [^t] - which matches anything except a t
- [ty]* is okay
- y is okay

Doing the above with the addition of `()?` for the middle group to allow it to match `ty` (by making so it is possible to have nothing inbetween t and y) means you end up with an alternative regex that passes the conditions above `^t([^t][ty]*)?y$`

Comment: ^t([^t][ty]*)?y$ suited my needs. much appreaciated.

Comment: However i still dont know why my second regex did not solve it? i wrote my explanation there, was i wrong in describing for that regex does?

Comment: plus i want to match this in part of a bigger regex 
(^|\s)t([^t][ty]*)?y$(?:([sm]*(sm)+[sm]*))?($|\s)
once i include it there it wont work because the $ is what makes it match y in the end.

Comment: however it answers the question i suppose so ive marked it solved

Comment: No worries, hope the edit I have made helps to answer your question. If you have another regex that doesn't work ask another question.

Comment: Understood. But, why do we need to specify an end and start using those chars? Talking about ur answer to my comment. Would it not already know that when i say (?!t) im trying to tell it to match NOT 't' right after the t, since i wrote it in that order?

Comment: Regex will search for a match _anywhere_ within the text you have given it so it can match within a word, using the start and end characters prevents it from matching things like tty as it will pick up the ty in tty.

Comment: @Ethicist as you can see from the linked demo, this regex matches words with characters other than `t` or `y` in them. So I don't think it actually answers your question (based on your original regex of `t[ty]*y` which will only match words with only `t` and `y` in them.

Comment: @Ethicist based on the difficulties you are having integrating this result, it would be better just to ask for a complete solution to your problem

Comment: @Nick no its okay, the questions were not supposed to be about integrating this result